# Spring Boot - Get all methods with custom annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reflection, annotations, kotlin

I have a custom annotation:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MustBeDocumented
annotation class Listener
```

Used like this:

```
@Service
class MyService {

   @Listener
   fun onNewThing(thing: Thing) {
       ...
   }
}
```

In another service, every time something happen, I want to call each function annotated with `@Listener` and with a parameter of type `Thing`.
How can I do it without looping through all the beans in the context and checking all the methods?

Comment: when the method of Thing was invoked, then notify the method of @Listener annotation?    you mean?

Comment: I have another service that receives some data of different types from an external service. Every time I get a new data, I parse it and then I want to call all the functions with the `@Listener` annotation and with a parameter of the type I just received

Comment: it would be much easier and controllable with spring AOP

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
Set<Method> methodsAnnotatedWith = new Reflections("com.example.spring.aop.api", new MethodAnnotationsScanner()).getMethodsAnnotatedWith(BusinessFunction.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use org.reflections of java :

`Set<Method> allMethods = new Reflections().getMethodsAnnotatedWith(yourAnnotation.class);`

```
for (Method m : allMethods) {
    if (m.isAnnotationPresent(yourAnnotation.class)) {
    //YOUR LOGIC
    }
}
```